# Mat select filter for object Array

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to introduce a search option in my mat-select DropDown.I went through a lot of similar working options, but those are not working for me because of the object array I am passing to the Dropdown. any help is appreciated. thank you.

**My Code**

HTML File

```
<mat-form-field>
   <mat-select (selectionChange)="getSubtier($event.value)">
     <input (keyup)="onKey($event.target.value)"> 
     <mat-option>None</mat-option>
     <mat-option *ngFor="let state of selectedStates" [value]="state">{{state.name}}</mat-option>
   </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

TS File

```
 states: string[] = [
        {
          toptier_agency_id: 15,
          create_date: 1517428376464,
          update_date: 1560547998012,
          toptier_code: "013",
          abbreviation: "DOC",
          name: "Department of Commerce",
          website: "https://www.commerce.gov/",
          mapped_org_name: "COMMERCE, DEPARTMENT OF",
          display_yn: "Y"
        },
        {
          toptier_agency_id: 16,
          create_date: 1517428376787,
          update_date: 1560547999157,
          toptier_code: "014",
          abbreviation: "DOI",
          name: "Department of the Interior",
          website: "https://www.doi.gov/",
          mapped_org_name: "INTERIOR, DEPARTMENT OF THE",
          display_yn: "Y"
        }];


 selectedValue: string;
  selectedStates = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.selectedStates = this.states;
  }
  onKey(value) {
    this.selectedStates = this.search(value);
  }
  getSubtier(value) {
    console.log(value);
  }

  search(value: string) {
    // this.selectedStates=[]
   // let filter = value.toLowerCase();
    // this.selectedStates = this.selectedStates['name'].filter((unit) => unit.label.indexOf(value) > -1);
  }
```

[StackBliz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-data-ct9uaa?file=app%2Fselect-form-example.ts)

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-select-search) ?

Comment: i tried that and it worked for me in stackbliz.., when i implement it in my code i am getting errors. and couldn't solve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify `search` functuon. Use `filter` and `includes`

Try like this:

```
onKey(value) {
  this.selectedStates = this.search(value);
}

search(value: string) {
  let filter = this.states.filter(item =>
    item.name.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())
  );
  return [...filter];
}
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-data-8uzdu6)**

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

introduce filter with an `isVisible` property

```
search(value: string) {
    return this.selectedStates.map(k => ({...k, isVisible:(k.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) > -1)}))  
}
```

add a getter for the filtered state

```
get filteredState() {
     return  this.selectedStates.filter(k=> k.isVisible === undefined || k.isVisible)
}
```

then in your html replace `selectedStates` with `filteredState`

```html
<mat-option *ngFor="let state of filteredState" [value]="state">{{state.name}}</mat-option>
```

> TS Note: that you should replace `states: string[]` with `states: any[]` or with the object you are using